# How do I insert incoming data only after a certain time?

Tags: c#

I'm coding for a microcontroller whereby my program constantly receives data from the microcontroller every second.

Is there such a way in c# coding whereby I can insert the data into database only after a certain period of time has passed? Maybe a time interval coding?

Comment: [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you wanting to buffer the data? It's not so clear really. Using a timer might work, but that may just cause other issues.

Comment: You could use a Timer in combination with a collection to store the data in. Or you use Reactive Extensions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) , some examples: http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc26, http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer . Reactive extensions is strong when it comes to apply a time factor to a stream of events.

Answer (score -2):

Combination of timer and data buffer should be helpful. Timer tick will free data buffer and will store it in DB

Comment: This should be a comment really.